# Laravel: replicate entire database schema

Tags: php, database, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

i am using Laravel with multiple database schemas - one per each client. what i would like to do is to copy / clone / replicate an entire client database. my Client model is set to automatically create a database on creation like this:

#### Client.php

```
static::created(function($client) {
    $createJob = new ClientCreate($client);
    app('Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher')->dispatch($createJob);
});
```

#### ClientCreate.php

```
DB::connection('admin')->statement("DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS {$dbName}_{$this->client->code} CASCADE");
DB::connection('admin')->statement("CREATE SCHEMA {$dbName}_{$this->client->code}");
DB::connection('admin')->statement("ALTER SCHEMA {$dbName}_{$this->client->code} OWNER TO postgres");

DB::connection('admin')->statement("GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA {$dbName}_{$this->client->code} TO {$dbName}_{$this->client->code}");
DB::connection('admin')->statement("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA {$dbName}_{$this->client->code} TO {$dbName}_dba WITH GRANT OPTION");
DB::connection('admin')->statement("GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA {$dbName}_{$this->client->code} TO postgres WITH GRANT OPTION");

DB::connection('admin')->statement("ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA {$dbName}_{$this->client->code} GRANT select, insert, update, delete ON TABLES TO {$dbName}_{$this->client->code}");
DB::connection('admin')->statement("ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA {$dbName}_{$this->client->code} GRANT select, insert, update, delete ON TABLES TO {$dbName}_{$this->client->code}");
DB::connection('admin')->statement("ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER postgres IN SCHEMA {$dbName}_{$this->client->code} GRANT select, insert, update, delete ON TABLES TO {$dbName}_{$this->client->code}");

DB::connection('admin')->statement("ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA {$dbName}_{$this->client->code} GRANT usage, select, update ON SEQUENCES TO {$dbName}_{$this->client->code}");
DB::connection('admin')->statement("ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA {$dbName}_{$this->client->code} GRANT usage, select, update ON SEQUENCES TO {$dbName}_{$this->client->code}");
DB::connection('admin')->statement("ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER postgres IN SCHEMA {$dbName}_{$this->client->code} GRANT usage, select, update ON SEQUENCES TO {$dbName}_{$this->client->code}");

DB::connection('admin')->statement("GRANT select, insert, update, delete ON public.users TO {$dbName}_{$this->client->code}");
DB::connection('admin')->statement("GRANT select, insert, update, delete ON public.client_user TO {$dbName}_{$this->client->code}");

Artisan::call('migrate:client', [
    'client' => $this->client->code,
]);
```

i also make it possible to activate the appropriate database by calling a method on the Client model:

#### public function activateDatabase()

```
$dbName = Config::get('database.connections.main.database');
Config::set('database.connections.client.schema', $dbName . '_' . $this->code);
Config::set('database.connections.client.username', $dbName . '_' . $this->code);
Config::set('database.connections.client.password', $dbName . '_' . $this->code);
Config::set('app.client', $this->code);

// reconnect to activate the new database settings
DB::reconnect('client');

// set the client as active
App::instance('App\Models\client', $this);
```

this allows me to create a new Client filled with attributes of the old one. it doesn't, however, copy all data from the tables in the database schema. to achieve this i would have to go through or the model or tables and replicate them manually.

my question is: is there a way to copy the entire database schema, so that i can have two identical clients with all the tables?

Comment: This might help you: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp